# Query multiple users and inner join to assets field

Tags: assets, users, join

How to query multiple users and join to assets field?

I want to query users with IDs `[1,3,4]` and `inner join` it to `assets` field with `volumeId` `5` and `title`s `[1,3,4]`.

Tried this but this is probably wrong (returns error):

```
$res = User::find()
  ->id([ 1, 2, 4 ])
  ->innerJoin('craft_assets assets', 'assets.volumeId=5')
  ->innerJoin('craft_content content, ', "content.title IN (1, 2, 4) ")
  ->createCommand()
  ->queryAll();

Craft::dd($res);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the point you want to inner join with the assets?  what kind of relation you wanted  between the user and the assets?

Comment: @aodihis I want to query users and join the assets with the name of the user IDs (those assets are named after the user IDs.